# Split words into variables

Tags: python, json, var

I'm reading an MP3 radio stream using Python and it prints out something like this

```
INXS~Disappear~RADIOSTATION~~MUSIC~~~360000~~~
```

I'd like to separate the words and place them in their own table / field.

The above is Artist, SongName, RadioStation, MUSIC, some number which I don't know what it is and doesn't ever change.

I've found something called word split but unsure if that will work.

I'm also unsure if a space in the song or artist name will cause any problems. The space isn't an underscore or anything clever, it is literally a space.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import datetime
import requests



stream_url = 'http://stream....'
request = urllib2.Request(stream_url)
try:
    request.add_header('Icy-MetaData', 1)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    icy_metaint_header = response.headers.get('icy-metaint')
    if icy_metaint_header is not None:
        metaint = int(icy_metaint_header)
        read_buffer = metaint+512
        content = response.read(read_buffer)
        title = content[metaint:].split("'")[1]
        print title
#       post_data = {'artist':'////', 'songname':'/////'}
#       post_response = requests.post(url='http:///////.co.uk', data=post_data)
        print datetime.datetime.now()
        import json


except:
     print 'null'
 #   print 'Error'
  #  print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the string's `split` method:

```
stream = "INXS~Disappear~RADIOSTATION~~MUSIC~~~360000~~~"
parts = stream.split("~")
```

with python it's even possible to directly assign the list elements returned by the split method to specific variables:

```
artist, songname, radiostation, music, number = [x for x in stream.split("~") if x]
```

I used a simple list comprehension to get rid of the empty elements in the list.

Instead of using a list comprehension you could use the filter built-in function to remove the empty elements:

```
 artist, songname, radiostation, music, number = filter(len, stream.split("~"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The split function will accomplish this for you. More information about string utils in the Python docs

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

```
 artist, song_name, radio_station, music, misc_number = string.split("~")
```

Comment: This does not work, because you'll have empty elements in the return value of `split` -> See my post

Comment: Depends on the placement and quantity of ~. The general idea about using split still stands. No need to down vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

st = 'INXS~Disappear~RADIOSTATION~~MUSIC~~~360000~~~'

names = ('artist', 'songname', 'radiostatino', 'music', 'number')

pp(list(zip(names,re.split(r'~+',st))))

[('artist', 'INXS'),
 ('songname', 'Disappear'),
 ('radiostatino', 'RADIOSTATION'),
 ('music', 'MUSIC'),
 ('number', '360000')]
```